# Use native UWP page in cordova custom plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm creating my custom cordova plugin. I already have windows component where is a xaml page which i'm using to work with camera and also have additional buttons on that page. Now i have to call and show this page from javascript in cordova.Is there any wrapper to do this. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried so far and share your code?

Comment: In my proxy javascript file i use other native methods, so i try to make a reference to the page WindowsComponnent.NativePage() and i get this error :
-The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread
Also i try to reference that page trough method with return type of Page  WindowsComponnent.NativeMethods.getNativePage() and get this error:
- The function 'getNativePage' has an invalid signature and cannot be called